# Media queries and making a grid system responsive

Tags: html, css, grid, media

I am kind of familiar with a media query but when it comes to multiple divs of different sizes and shapes, I get completely lost. So, if someone would be willing to walk me through the process, that would be wonderful. Or just maybe give me some pointers, that's all I'm really asking for! Right now I have 7 separate divs, all positioned how I would like, just not sure how to keep it responsive for different devices.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
    
}.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;

}

.one:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}


.two:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.three:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.two { 
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 /3;
}

.two:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 /3;
}
.four {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}
.five {
  grid-column: 1 /3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.six {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 ;
}
.seven {
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="one"><div class="oneimage"></div><div class="onetext">Title here</div></div>
 <div onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="two">Title here</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
  <div class="seven">Seven</div>


      </div>
```

Thank you to whoever decides to help me in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .wrapper {
   display: block;
 }
 .margin-bot {
   margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
}
```

I gave an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0y4dru97/) of what a possible solution would look like. If you change the display to block on mobile then you get each div stacked on top of one another. You can see the change in action if you change the size of the screen in jsfiddle. I also added some margin to the bottom of each div because they were touch each other. Please let me know if you need any further help!

Comment: How can I go about making them stack together then using media queries?

Comment: Perfect! One last thing... how can I go about getting a different image within each box?

Comment: So in your CSS you can change the images by using 'background-image'. You can see more information in the link below. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: I followed the information you listed above but everytime I place an image in the css for a certain div, the image is super zoomed in and blurry and I have to manually position it to get it center or to fill a certain block. How can i go about avoiding this?

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/c9jvr9L3/, the dog image is zoomed in and everything, then in mobile view it looks fine. How can I go about fixing this?